# Referenciar scripts em diferentes páginas PHP

Tags: php, javascript, script, import

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:
|- /root
|-- /services
|--- /cadastros
|-- /view
|--- dashboard.php
|--- menu.php
|--- /cadastros
|---- /pessoas
|----- Incluir_Pessoas.php
|-- /scripts
|-- menu.js

Dentro da dashboard.php eu tenho o seguinte javascript: $("body").load("menu.php") que é utilizado para popular uma navbar com as opções.
- Dentro de menu.php eu tenho a importação do arquivo menu.js

O problema acontece quando eu tento popular o mesmo menu dentro de "Incluir_Pessoas.php" pois ele esta pegando o caminho relativo à esse arquivo (root/cadastros/pessoas). Mesmo eu utilizando no load o caminho "../../menu.php" ele tenta procurar o menu.js no diretorio referente à root/cadastros/pessoas/.

Teria uma forma de eu importar esses arquivos de forma obsoluta, sem ter que deixar todos os arquivos no mesmo diretório?

Answer (score 0):

Se for num arquivo PHP você poderia fazer algo do gênero:

`__DIR__ . '../../quantasPastasVocePrecisarVoltar';`

a constante mágica ***DIR*** serve para indicar o caminho atual, aí a partir do caminho atual você volta ou avança pastas normalmente conforme a necessidade.